unable to get logger for spring boot log groups
application.properties
logging.level.root=info
logging.level.test=warn
logging.level.mygroup=error
logging.group.mygroup=com.aaa.bbb

java code
@Slf4j
//...
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
System.out.println(logger.getLevel());

when the name is root, print INFO
when the name is test, pring WARN
when the name is mygroup, print null not ERROR
Is it possible to get the logger for group?
If not, is there any workaround?
p.s. My intention is to set (overwrite) the log level dynamically.
